# How to reliably determine when UICollectionView layout has finished animating

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm having problems figuring out a way to determine when UICollectionView is/has finished animating.

I currently have a UICollectionView that animates between two subclassed flow layouts using `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:`

The animation looks great, however, I'm having some undesired behaviour if a user selects a cell *during* the animation.

I'm looking at ignoring the cell 'selection' by returning `NO` through the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:` - however - I cannot figure out a reliable test to see if the collection view is currently animating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking that there are no animation keys.
`BOOL isAnimating = myView.layer.animationKeys.count > 0`

Comment: Thanks - that worked.  Interestingly, I had to check the animation keys on the animating cells, NOT the UICollectionView.  This meant iterating through visible cells checking for animation.  My final code .. `- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.myCollectionView visibleCells];
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        if (cell.layer.animationKeys.count > 0) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
` (NB. import QuartzCore.h to access `layer`)